# LWC Jest: test a component that uses lightning/toast

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest, toast, mock

The `lightning/toast` utility is [GA as of Winter '24](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_toastcontainer.htm&release=246&type=5), but I haven't seen anything on StackExchange or in the docs about how to write tests for components that use it. One you import it into a component and try to run Jest tests, you get an error like this:

```
Cannot find module 'lightning/toast' from 'force-app/main/default/lwc/myApp/myApp.js'
```

I'm doing a Q&A-style entry here for posterity. The solution is simple enough if you know about mocking patterns in Jest + LWC, but I'm sure many devs will encounter this error, search Google for it, and end up here.

Answer (score 0):

In keeping with the mocking approach suggested by the [Lightning Web Components Tests](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/test-lightning-web-components/mock-other-components) Trailhead module, here are the steps:

1. Create this directory in your SFDX repo if it doesn't already exist: `force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning`
2. Add a new file, `toast.js`, to the above directory. A very basic stub like this should work for most use cases:

```js
export default class Toast {
  static show() {}
}
```

3. Update the `jest.config.js` file in the root of your repo. Add or update the `moduleNameMapper` property of `module.exports` as follows to include a new property, `^lightning/toast$`, pointing to the mock's file path:

```js
...
module.exports = {
  ...
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^lightning/toast$": "<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/toast"
  }
};
```

Jest will now use the stub, and it will no longer complain about not being able to find `lightning/toast`.